# how should I generate the app.module.ngfactory.ts file?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get my angular2 app set up for AOT. It seems that an `app.module.ngfactory.ts` file is needed for this instead of the standard `app.module.ts` file used for `JIT` compilation. I have a working `app.module.ts` for my standard JIT app. How can I go about converting the contents of this file into the expected format for `app.module.ngfactory.ts`?

Answer (score 5):

You need to compile it using `ngc`. The basic steps are:

1) install aot compiler

```
npm install @angular/compiler-cli
```

2) add configuration to `tsconfig.json`:

```
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
   "genDir": "aot",
   "skipMetadataEmit" : true
 }
```

And then you can run `ngc`:

```
node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig.json
```

In the output `aot` folder you will see `app.module.ngfactory.ts` file.

You can read more about it [here](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#compile-with-aot).

Comment: Be aware that as of Angular 5 *.ngfactory.ts is no longer generated.